# Derive value in XML from environment variable

Tags: xml, linux, ubuntu

I have a XML file with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Get name="securityHandler">
        <Set name="authenticator">
            <New class="org.keycloak.adapters.jetty.KeycloakJettyAuthenticator">
                <Set name="adapterConfig">
                    <New class="org.keycloak.representations.adapters.config.AdapterConfig">
                        <Set name="realm">test-realm</Set>
                        <Set name="resource">$KC_CLIENTID</Set>
                        <Set name="authServerUrl">$KC_URL</Set>
                        <Set name="sslRequired">external</Set>
                        <Set name="bearerOnly">true</Set>
                        <Set name="confidentialPort">0</Set>
                    </New>
                </Set>
            </New>
        </Set>
    </Get>
</Configure>
```

I am looking for XML processor that reads values from environment and replace according to the values that was set in the environment.

For example, I set `$KC_URL=http://localhost:8080/auth/` and after proceeding with a XML processor it should show:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Get name="securityHandler">
        <Set name="authenticator">
            <New class="org.keycloak.adapters.jetty.KeycloakJettyAuthenticator">
                <Set name="adapterConfig">
                    <New class="org.keycloak.representations.adapters.config.AdapterConfig">
                        <Set name="realm">test-realm</Set>
                        <Set name="resource">test</Set>
                        <Set name="authServerUrl">http://localhost:8080/auth/</Set>
                        <Set name="sslRequired">external</Set>
                        <Set name="bearerOnly">true</Set>
                        <Set name="confidentialPort">0</Set>
                    </New>
                </Set>
            </New>
        </Set>
    </Get>
</Configure>
```

Does it exist such a XML processor for linux?

Answer (score 0):

Using xmlstarlet, you could do it using this:

```
xml ed  -u '//Set[@name="resource"]' -v $KC_URL file.xml
```